# Por qué me sale este error? Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_cordovaNative') al lanzar una app con cordova y android studios

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, studio

Estoy haciendo una app hibrida con cordova, y al lanzarla con android studio recibo este error en la consola.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_cordovaNative')
    at cordova.js:340:22
    at build (cordova.js:47:9)
    at require (cordova.js:62:24)
    at localRequire (cordova.js:43:20)
    at cordova.js:932:25
    at build (cordova.js:47:9)
    at require (cordova.js:62:24)
    at localRequire (cordova.js:43:20)
    at Object.bootstrap (cordova.js:1420:20)
    at cordova.js:1281:32
```

Además, debajo de esto recibo estos cuatro errores controlados,

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1230 Channel not fired: onNativeReady
cordova.js:1230 Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
cordova.js:1230 Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
```

La cosa es que lanza la aplicación correctamente, pero trato de hacer inicio de sesión con google y twitter, y estos enlaces no hacen nada, cuando lo lanzo en la web si que funcionan correctamente.

Estoy haciendo una app hibrida con cordova, y al lanzarla con android studio recibo este error en la consola.